# Python Regex: Ignore Escaped Character

Tags: python, regex, pcre

Alright, I'm currently using Python's regular expression library to split up the following string into groups of semicolon delimited fields.

`'key1:"this is a test phrase"; key2:"this is another test phrase"; key3:"ok this is a gotcha\; but you should get it";'`

Regex: `\s*([^;]+[^\\])\s*;`

I'm currently using the pcre above, which was working fine until I encountered a case where an escaped semicolon is included in one of the phrases as noted above by key3.

How can I modify this expression to only split on the non-escaped semicolons?

Comment: What happened when you tried the `\;` in the sample above? Seems like it should fail to match until after that point. Is the `[^\\]` in your pattern an attempted workaround for this issue, or does that have some significance besides dealing with `\;`?

Comment: May the quoted strings contain escaped quotes? i.e. `key:" \" ";` And may the quoted strings contain non-escaped semicolons? i.e. `key:" ; ";`?

Comment: Justin, it was an attempted work around for this issue. The first two groups are correctly parsed, but the odd (last) group ends up just being 'but you should get it";', chopping off the block before the escaped semicolon.

Comment: Ridgerunner, the semicolons and quotes in the string must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

The basic version of this is where you want to ignore any `;` that's preceded by a backslash, regardless of anything else. That's relatively simple:

```
\s*([^;]*[^;\\]);
```

What will make this tricky is if you want *escaped* backslashes in the input to be treated as literals. For example:

```
"You may want to split here\\;"
"But not here\;"
```

If that's something you want to take into account, try this **(edited)**:

```
\s*((?:[^;\\]|\\.)+);
```

Why so complicated? Because if escaped backslashes are allowed, then you have to account for things like this:

```
"0 slashes; 2 slashes\\; 5 slashes\\\\\; 6 slashes\\\\\\;"
```

Each pair of doubled backslashes would be treated as a literal `\`. That means a `;` would only be escaped if there were an *odd number* of backslashes before it. So the above input would be grouped like this:

```
#1: '0 slashes'
#2: '2 slashes\'
#3: '5 slashes\\; 6 slashes\\\'
```

Hence the different parts of the pattern:

```
\s*            #Whitespace
((?:
    [^;\\]     #One character that's not ; or \
  |            #Or...
    \\.        #A backslash followed by any character, even ; or another backslash
)+);           #Repeated one or more times, followed by ;
```

Requiring a character after a backslash ensures that the second character is always escaped properly, even if it's another backslash.

Comment: Do we really need negative look behind or I am missing something?

Comment: @Abhijit - If you're not differentiating between `\;` and `\\;`, then you don't need one (hence my second pattern, which doesn't have one). If you want to treat `\\;` as a literal backslash and split on the `;` as normal, then I don't see any other way of doing it.

Comment: @JohnDoe - So negative lookbehinds are allowed, but not if they're variable-length like my last pattern. In that case, I can't think of a regex that will detect escaped backslashes in the input.

Comment: @JohnDoe - I think I spoke too soon. Check the edited pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If the string may contain semicolons and escaped quotes (or escaped *anything*), I would suggest parsing each valid `key:"value";` sequence. Like so:

```py
import re
s = r'''
    key1:"this is a test phrase";
    key2:"this is another test phrase";
    key3:"ok this is a gotcha\; but you should get it";
    key4:"String with \" escaped quote";
    key5:"String with ; unescaped semi-colon";
    key6:"String with \\; escaped-escape before semi-colon";
    '''
result = re.findall(r'\w+:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*";', s)
print (result)
```

Note that this correctly handles any escapes within the double quoted string.